# How to get a registry read function to work properly? (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

When I compile and run the following code snippet (in visual studio 2019),
it runs but returns an incorrect value of

```
Key Value: 000000D1E14FF920 and actual bytes read was: 12
```

instead of

```
Key Value: 18363 and actual bytes read was: 6
```

here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

wchar_t value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(value);
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\"), _T("CurrentBuildNumber"), RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
std::cout << "Key Value: " << value << " and actual bytes read was: " << BufferSize << std::endl;
```

I tried multiple methords of fixing this problem but I couldnt get it to work properly with visual studio (probably because it uses unicode)

Comment: That looks like it's printing the pointer value and number of bytes, while you expect the contents of the array as a wide string, and character count. Assuming it's a Unicode compile, use `std::wcout` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `char` and `TCHAR` APIs. It is clear that `RegGetValue()` is returning a Unicode wide string, because 12 bytes is correct for a 6-character null-terminated `wchar_t` string.  So  `TCHAR` is mapping to `wchar_t` in your build, and thus `RegGetValue()` is calling `RegGetValueW()`.  You are trying to print out that wide string using `std::cout`, which does not support `wchar_t` strings, so you are actually calling the `void*` overload of `std::basic_osteam::operator<<`. That is why you are seeing a memory address being printed out.

To deal with `TCHAR` correctly, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
#define tcout std::wcout
#else
#define tcout std::cout
#endif

TCHAR value[255] = {};
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(value);
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\"), _T("CurrentBuildNumber"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &value, &BufferSize);

tcout << _T("Key Value: ") << value << _T(" and actual bytes read was: ") << (BufferSize / sizeof(TCHAR)) << std::endl;
```

However, you really should forget that `TCHAR` exists, it has no place in modern coding anymore.  Just go full Unicode only:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

WCHAR value[255] = {}
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(value);
RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\", L"CurrentBuildNumber", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &value, &BufferSize);

std::wcout << L"Key Value: " << value << L" and actual bytes read was: " << (BufferSize / sizeof(WCHAR)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer and the second code snippet worked perfectly! Many thanks.